# problems with german umlauts in php json_encode

Tags: php, json, character-encoding

I'm getting troubles with data from a database containing german umlauts. Basically, whenever I receive a data containing umlauts, it is a black square with an interrogation mark. I solved this by putting

```
mysql_query ('SET NAMES utf8')
```

before the query.

The problem is, as soon as I use `json_encode(...)` on a result of a query, the value containing an umlaut gets `null`. I can see this by calling the php-file directly in the browser. Are there other solution than replacing this characters before encoding to JSON and decoding it in JS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably just want to show the texts somehow in the browser, so one option would be to change the umlauts to HTML entities by using [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities).

The following test worked for me:

```
<?php
    $test = array( 'bla' => 'äöü' );
    $test['bla'] = htmlentities( $test['bla'] );

    echo json_encode( $test );
?>
```

Answer (score 41):

Check out this pretty elegant solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21550697/2593099):

```
json_encode( $json_full, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
```

If the problem isn't anywhere else in your code this should fix it.

**Edit:** Umlaut problems can be caused by a variety of sources like the charset of your HTML document, the database format or some previous php functions your strings run through (You should definitely look into [multibyte functions](https://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.mbstring.php) when having problems with umlauts).

These problems tend to be the pretty annoying because they are hard to track in most cases (altough this isn't as bad as it was a few years ago). The function above fixes – as asked – umlaut problems with json_encode … but there is a good chance that the problem is caused by a different part of your application and not this specific function.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. saved a lot of time, thanks

Comment: While the accepted answer had many problems, this answer worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

I know this might be old but here a better solution:

Define the document type with utf-8 charset:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

Make sure that all content is utf_encoded. JSON works only with utf-8!

```
function encode_items(&$item, $key)
{
    $item = utf8_encode($item);
}
array_walk_recursive($rows, 'encode_items');
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 5):

The only important point here is that json_encode() only supports UTF-8 encoding. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

> All string data must be UTF-8 encoded.

So when you have any special characters in a non utf-8 string json_encode will return a null Value.

So either you switch the whole project to utf-8 or you make sure you utf8_encode() any string before using json_encode().

Answer (score 0):

make sure the translation file itself was explicitely stored as UTF-8

After that reload cache blocks and translations