# Json_encode umlauts output

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress, jsonp

I want to show my output in German umlauts, i got my output like this for example Fu009\ but i need "fü" like this.

```
<?php
$json = (object) array(
    "salutation" = > ''.$order - > order_custom_fields['_billing_anrede'][0].
    '',
    "title" = > ''.$order - > order_custom_fields['_billing_titel'][0].
    '',
    "first_name" = > ''.$order - > order_custom_fields['_billing_first_name'][0].
    '',
    "last_name" = > ''.$order - > order_custom_fields['_billing_last_name'][0].
    '',
    "street" = > ''.$order - > order_custom_fields['_billing_address_1'][0].
    '',
    "street_number" = > ''.$order - > order_custom_fields['_billing_address_2'][0].
    '',
    "address_supplement" = > ''.$order - > order_custom_fields['_billing_company'][0].
    '',
    "zipcode" = > ''.$order - > order_custom_fields['_billing_postcode'][0].
    '',
    "city" = > ''.$order - > order_custom_fields['_billing_city'][0].
    '',
    "country" = > ''.$pais.
    '',
    "terms_accepted" = > true,
    "receiving_mails_accepted" = > ''.$email.
    '',
    "email" = > ''.$order - > order_custom_fields['_billing_email'][0].
    '',
    "lottery_accepted" = > false,
    "lottery_solution" = > "LOTTERY",
    "original_created_at" = > ''.date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP', strtotime($order - > order_date)).
    '',


);

foreach($items as $item) {
    $sku = $wpdb - > get_var($wpdb - > prepare('SELECT meta_value FROM dsr_postmeta WHERE meta_key="_sku" AND post_id='.$item['product_id'].
        ''));
    $sku_s = explode('-', $sku);
    $camp = $sku_s[0];
    $itm_n = $sku_s[1];
    $json - > items[] = (object) array(
        "campaign_number" = > (int) $camp,
        "item_number" = > (int) $itm_n,

    );
}



array_push($json_full, $json);
echo json_encode($json_full);
?>
```

I'm thinking about htmlentities, or utf8
thanks for you help!!

Comment: You already have the answer. Just use HTML entities

Comment: but how?         
     <?php
$json_full = htmlentities($json_full);
  echo json_encode($json_full);

  ?> like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you are using PHP 5.4+, change `echo json_encode($json_full);` to  `echo json_encode($json_full, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

Full list of `json_encode` predefined constants can be found there: https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

## Demonstration

Code:

```
<?php
$json = (object) array(
  "uml" => "fü",
);

echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) . PHP_EOL;

echo json_encode($json) . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
{"uml":"fü"}
{"uml":"f\u00fc"}
```

Comment: You are definitely missing something. I updated my answer with example.

Comment: your example too doesnt work me, in the second output i got uml : null,  i dont know what is the problem

Comment: Please provide your exact PHP version

Comment: Well thats a answer +1

Answer (score 0):

Do you have set your charset correctly?

```
<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
```