# German Umlaut / Special characters in userInfo NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I currently set up an app which receives push messages from Amazon SNS (which works fine).
On the PHP side, I use a normal JSON-similar payload which goes like this:

```
'aps' => array(
                    'content-available' => 1,
                    'alert' => array('body' => 'Text with or without Umlaut (ÄÖÜ)'),
                    'badge' => 1,
                    'sound' => 'default'
                )
```

So my issue is: If I send a notification containing Umlauts (Ä,Ö,Ü), the Push Badge in the upper part show the text properly upon receveing this.
However, my app doesn't: It receives < null>.
I process messages in a normal didreceveive...

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
```

So I logged the received userInfo dictionary as the first thing in this method and here I received the :

```
NSLog(@"userInfo=%@",userInfo);


alert =         {
        body = "<null>";
    };
    badge = 1;
    "content-available" = 1;
    sound = default;
```

Without umlauts- it works fine!
There aren't any questions regarding this and that's why I would appreciate any input right now...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and if your are sending notifications without german umlauts (Umlauts hört sich voll seltsam in Englisch an :D) does that work? Or do you getting the same/other errors?

Comment: Hi Krummy, yeah exactly that's the issue - it works 100% without these umlauts! The translation according to dict.cc is "special character". ;)

Comment: you could try to set the "charset" within the header (there are possibilites for html, php, android and so on.. you may need to google it :D). An example would be <?php header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); ?>

Comment: Thanks for the answer- yes the issue was that I use a PHP formula called JSON_ENCODE (I'm not a PHP expert), which uses ASC II !  Your solution didn't solve this, however I'll keep you posted !

Comment: You still mus verify that all your statements are "translated" into uft-8. Have a look at my answer below. I hope i can point you at least into the right direction ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [article on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602075/problems-with-german-umlauts-in-php-json-encode). Both of the solution i post are there with some comments. Hop it helps you.

**Solution 1:**

You can define the document type with utf-8 charset (like written in a comment on qour question):

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

Make sure that all content is utf_encoded. JSON works only with utf-8!

```
function encode_items(&$item, $key)
{
    $item = utf8_encode($item);
}
array_walk_recursive($rows, 'encode_items');
```

**Solution 2:**

Another solution would be to use `htmlentities()`.

```
<?php
    $test = array( 'bla' => 'äöü' );
    $test['bla'] = htmlentities( $test['bla'] );

    echo json_encode( $test );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful! To sum it up, I declared all strings which will be sent via apns like this:        $push_title = utf8_encode('Title with or without Umlaut ÜÖÄ');  ==> the system itself displays them correctly, I just didn't realize this instantly - I only looked at the console and it prints the pure UTF.... don't let the console make you do more work --!