# How to convert array containing umlaut characters(ääää) into json

Tags: php, json

I have written this php code for converting umlaut characters (`ääää`) to use in a json string, but it is not returning the exact result I want.

Code:

```
mysql_set_charset("ut8");
$size = "ääää";
$d=utf8_encode($size);
echo $de= json_encode($d);
```

Result:

```
ÃƒÂ¤ÃƒÂ¤ÃƒÂ¤ÃƒÂ¤
```

Expected result:

```
ääää
```

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Have you tried without the ``utf8_encode``? If your file is saved as UTF8, you do not need to use that function.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602075/problems-with-german-umlauts-in-php-json-encode

Comment: Sidenote: [Do not use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set content type json for that by using header and with json_encode use the second parameter ie. **JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE**

```
    header('Content-Type: application/json; Charset=UTF-8');
    mysql_set_charset("ut8");
    $size = "ääää";
    echo $de= json_encode($size,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Although the code may or may not come from a mysql database, the `mysql_set_charset()` function does not do anything usefull here when the string is already stored in a variable.

Comment: I've tested your code, the `utf8_encode()` is not needed and will break the code. The header should be removed, as the OP didn't ask for the json to be sent directly to the users browser (it seems that he wants to store it in a database). Just `json_encode($size,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` is enough.

Comment: yes that was by written by mistake i have edited the code

Comment: Its working on the system after removing $d=utf8_encode($size); and $size to be added in the json_encode string

Comment: yeah but remove the `header()` and `mysql_set_charset()` functions from your answer as well. Then it's correct and down to the point, and you'll earn a +1 from me ;)

Comment: I have tried your approach giorgio but not working it is giving the different result

Answer (score 0):

Here is a useful function for anyone who stumbles into this issue in the future:
[php function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#106417)