# PHP print_r works, but json_encode returns empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, json

My php code looks like this:

```
$header = "Content-Type: application/json";
header($header);

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {

    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

} 

$sql = "SELECT * ...";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$array_1 = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data as array
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        array_push($array_1, $row);

    }
}

$conn->close();

print_r($array_1);
```

Which gives me the following ouput:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_email] => test@gmail.com
            [order_item_name] => Abonnement
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_email] => test@gmail.com
            [order_item_name] => Verlängerung
        )

)
```

This output is the result of a query by email, in order to return the name of the product. In this case, if I change `print_r` with `echo json_encode` nothing appears. This makes me believe that the problem has to do with the charset given that the result is not empty, so I added:

```
$header = "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8";
header($header);
```

Still no luck. I have been reading that it may be the case that the json* functions are disabled, however, if I change the email from my query it displays the result as above using `print_r` and as json using `echo json_encode` perfectly fine. It must be from this result the root of the problem, or any similar scenario. Can it be because of the character **ä** from the result? Thats why I added utf-8 in the header.

As I said above, if I change the email it works, but it shows only 1 results instead 2 when I use "test@gmail.com". Can it be that the results are not put in the array correctly? I believe not given that `print_r` formats the query result correctly.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($array_1)`? var_dump is always more helpful to debug ;)

Comment: Try `$json_string = json_encode($array_1); var_dump($json_string);`

Comment: Do both, var_dump($array); then echo json_encode($array);
There is no reason that it does not work.
If a function does not exist, you get a warning/error you are using a function that it is not existing. Ensure you display all warning using error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Ask `json_last_error`. And yes, it's mostly encoding issues.

Comment: on `var_dump($json_string)` I get bool(false) @Fabian N @Brian @Loenix

Comment: Thanks all for so quick responses!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

json_encode only supports UTF-8 encoded strings, so you'll have to encode your `order_item_name` values using either `htmlentities` or `utf8_encode`

```
foreach($array1 as &$v) {
  $v['order_item_name'] = utf8_encode($v['order_item_name']);
}

print json_encode($array1);
```

For more info see [problems with german umlauts in php json_encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602075/problems-with-german-umlauts-in-php-json-encode)

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks you very much!